# Render problem in layout xml - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, xml-layout

When I am trying to add a TextView in layout xml, the rendering of views does not occur and the design tab becomes empty.

This is the stacktrace shown in Studio

**Render problem**

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:268)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:294)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:131)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:318)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:358)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:701)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:848)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:200)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:298)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.InputStream.available()" because "assetStream" is null
at android.graphics.fonts.Font_Builder_Delegate.createBuffer(Font_Builder_Delegate.java:52)
at android.graphics.fonts.Font$Builder.createBuffer(Font.java:264)
at android.graphics.fonts.Font$Builder.(Font.java:200)
at android.graphics.Typeface$Builder.(Typeface.java:517)
at android.graphics.Typeface_Delegate.createFromDisk(Typeface_Delegate.java:91)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getFont(ResourceHelper.java:495)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getFont(ResourceHelper.java:507)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getFont(BridgeTypedArray.java:723)
at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:4154)
at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1165)
at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1066)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:113)
at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.(MaterialTextView.java:92)
at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.(MaterialTextView.java:87)
at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createTextView(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:61)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:148)
... 28 more

I have tried updating Studio to latest version, still it did not solve it.

**Details of AS**

Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709, built on January 19, 2024

Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please visit the help center, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also please see [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your question